# Uncaught ReferenceError: ctx is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've tried everything to solve this problem and nothings working. Posting here is my last resort.

I'm trying to code a simple canvas element and load everything dynamically and nothing is working. I keep getting the error in Google console "Uncaught ReferenceError: ctx is not defined" on game.js:33.

I originally thought it was because common.js is being loaded after the other 2 javascript files so I made a loader file which loads each JS file in the order I want. I did this using $.getScript() and the $.when() function . Unfortunately, this did not work. So the ctx var is being loaded but it's giving me the error for some reason.

I've included the files below. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I just tried taking all the code out of each individual JS file and putting them in the same one in the order they are meant to be in and it works fine now. But it would be nice to know why it was not working at all. As it's going to get very hectic having all my code in 1 file. Thank you.

**index.php**

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Game - Unknown</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/default.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.3.min.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="./assets/js/loader.js"></script>-->
   <script src="./assets/js/common.js"></script>
   <script src="./assets/js/graphics.js"></script>
   <script src="./assets/js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      // Setup the canvas game context for 2D
      var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // Update the canvas dimensions to match window size when changed
      $(window).resize(function(){canvasResize()}); canvasResize();

      function canvasResize(){
         var cWidth = window.innerWidth;
         var cHeight = window.innerHeight;

         canvas.width = cWidth;
         canvas.height = cHeight;

         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
         ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
      }

      // Get center of things - Useful for centering images on canvas
      function getCenter(dim){ return dim / 2 }

   });
```

**graphics.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      function gfxTile(x, y, w, h, r, g, b, a)
      {
         ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(60, 60, 100)";
         ctx.beginPath();
         //ctx.moveTo(x + h / 2, y + w / 2);
         ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
         ctx.lineTo(105, 25);
         ctx.lineTo(25, 105);
         ctx.lineTo(25, 105);
         ctx.closePath();
         ctx.fill();
      }

   });
```

**game.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      // START TEMPORARY
      var mapSizeX = 10;
      var mapSizeY = 10;
      var mapArray = new Array();

      function createMap()
      {
         for(x = 0; x < mapSizeX; x++)
         {
            mapArray[x] = [];

            for(y = 0; y < mapSizeY; y++)
            {
               mapArray[x][y] = 0;
            }
         }
      }
      // END TEMPORARY

      setInterval(mainLoop, 50);

      function mainLoop()
      {
         //gfxTile(10, 10, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 100);
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }

   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` created a variable called `ctx` in the scope of the function you passed into `$(document).ready();`

When the function inside of game.js executes, there is no `ctx` variable in its scope, or the parent scope, `window`.

An easy fix would be changing

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

to

```
window.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Oh I see! I did not know that $(document).ready() had a local scope and thought everything inside that but outside of a function would act as global. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your ctx variable is already on a reachable namespace, your problem is basically a result of loading files with no order and priority. You can however use a script loader to solve the problem and make sure your variable is already defined before using it.

In this example I'm using the [head.js](http://headjs.com/) script loader.

```
<script src="js/head.js"></script>
<script>
head.js(
"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
    "http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.3.min.js", 
    "js/common.js", 
    "js/graphics.js", 
    "js/game.js"
);
```

You can optimize your code even more using [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to expose only the namespaces you want . Check them out.